# Silverstripe returning a populated form via controller

Tags: forms, controller, silverstripe

I am trying to figure out the correct way of returning back a form that is pre-populated with data from the database.  Let me show you how I am doing it right now:

TeamsPage:

```
<?php
class TeamsPage extends Page {
  private static $has_many = array (
    'Teams' => 'Team',
  );
  public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Teams', GridField::create(
        'Teams',
        'Teams on this page',
        $this->Teams(),
        GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
    ));
    return $fields;
  }
}
class TeamsPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
  private static $allowed_actions = array (
    'show', 'edit', 'EditTeamForm'
  );

  public function EditTeamForm($teamId){
    $fields = new FieldList(
        new TextField('TeamName'),
        new TextareaField('TeamDescription')
    );
    $actions = new FieldList(
        new FormAction('EditTeam', 'Save Changes')
    );
    $requiredFields = new RequiredFields(array('TeamName','TeamDescription'));
    $form = new Form($this, 'EditTeamForm', $fields, $actions, $requiredFields);
    $form->setFormMethod('POST', true);

    $data = Session::get("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data");
    $team = Team::get()->byID($teamId);
    return $data ? $form->loadDataFrom($data) : $form->loadDataFrom($team);
  }

  public function show(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
    $team = Team::get()->byID($request->param('ID'));

    if(!$team) {
        return $this->httpError(404,'That team could not be found');
    }

    return array (
        'Team' => $team
    );
  }

  public function edit(SS_HTTPRequest $request){
    $team = Team::get()->byID($request->param('ID'));

    if(!$team) {
        return $this->httpError(404,'That team could not be found');
    }

    return array (
        'Team' => $team
    );
  }
}
```

Team:

```
<?php
class Team extends DataObject {
  private static $db = array(
    'TeamCaptain' => 'Int',
    'TeamName' => 'Varchar',
    'TeamDescription' => 'Text'
  );
  private static $has_one = array (
    'Photo' => 'Image',
    'TeamsPage' => 'TeamsPage'
  );
  private static $summary_fields = array (
    'GridThumbnail' => '',
    'TeamCaptain' => 'Team Captain',
    'TeamName' => 'TeamName',
    'TeamDescription' => 'Team Description',
  );
  public function getGridThumbnail() {
    if($this->Photo()->exists()) {
        return $this->Photo()->SetWidth(100);
    }
    return '(no image)';
  }
  public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('TeamCaptain'),
        TextField::create('TeamName'),
        TextareaField::create('TeamDescription'),
        $uploader = UploadField::create('Photo')
    );
    $uploader->setFolderName('teams-photos');
    $uploader->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(array(
        'png','gif','jpeg','jpg'
    ));
    return $fields;
  }

  public function Link() {
    return $this->TeamsPage()->Link('show/'.$this->ID);
  }
}
```

TeamsPage_edit.ss

```
<% if GetMember() %>
  Welcome $getMember.FirstName<br />
  $EditTeamForm($Team.ID)
  <a href="home">Back to Home</a>
<% else %>
  $GoToLogin()
<% end_if %>
```

As you can see in my controller I am returning a $Team that I don't fully understand how it works.  In my template I use $Team.ID and I am trying to figure out if that value comes from me returning array of Teams or somehow else.  The other thing I am trying to understand is why do I not return a Form here, why do I have to have a sepparate function to create that form and have to call it as such in the template.  The last problem that I see here is that I am querying the database twice for the same information.

What I am asking in the end is If anyone could show me what would be the proper way to achieve what I am doing.  I'm sure it has been done many times, but I could not find a single example anywhere on the internet of how to use edit forms.  I have found how to use show action and return bunch of results, but nothing in combination with the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest simply doing the following (these are additions to your code, not a complete class):

```
class TeamPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    protected $currentTeam;

    protected function getCurrentTeam() {
        if (!isset($this->currentTeam)) {
            $teamID = $this->getRequest()->param('ID') ?: $this->getRequest()->postVar('ID');
            $this->currentTeam = $teamID ? Team::get()->byID($teamID) : null;
        }
        return $this->currentTeam;
    }

    public function EditTeamForm() {
         $team = $this->getCurrentTeam();             
         // You'll want to add a HiddenField with the ID if $team is not null
         // everything else is the same
    }

    // NOTE: I would suggest you call this something else
    // SS convention would be "doSaveTeam" - it should be whatever your FormAction is called though
    public function EditTeam($data, $form) {
        $team = $this->getCurrentTeam();
        // Save and redirect
    }

    public function edit(SS_HTTPRequest $request){
        $team = $this->getCurrentTeam();
        // Blah blah blah
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting this.  I have couple of questions.  The edit function returns a team.  In order to use this in the template, it has to return Team, is that correct?  Another question is, why can't I return a pre-populated form instead of a team?  Not having to call it from template but by default the page loads in the form via the function edit.

Comment: First, the edit function returns an array that is used to populate the template. It can return the form object as part of the array if you'd rather.

But second, you need EditTeamForm() to be callable on it's own steam because the controller will not go through edit() again when the form is submitted. It will build the form directly from EditTeamForm and then call the submission handler (EditTeam which I counseled you to rename doSaveTeam). That's why it's best to not pass anything into that method.

Comment: those are good explanations thank you!  I am making one more disconnect, The edit function returns an array as you say, in this case it returns an array that contains $team.  On my template I have $Team.ID, exactly how does silverstripe knows that the $team I returned is actually $Team that I am using.  I'm basically trying to understand how does does it go from $team in edit to $Team in template.  I apologize for so many questions but I'm trying to get the whole picture as its important for me to understand what I am implementing.  Especially when it comes to debugging later on.

Comment: No problem. It's called $Team in the template because the key in the array you return is 'Team'. If you returned array('MyTeam' => $team) you would access it with $MyTeam in the template. You could actually also use $CurrentTeam in the template because you have a getCurrentTeam method on the controller (but you'd have to make it public first).

Comment: Your answers are amazing, one last thing occurred to me, if I had a www.mywebsite.com/teams/create what would the controller of create return?  Because I'm only creating, it doesn't need to query for any teams, besides check if it exists but I would do that in doCreateTeam function I would make that would be called by CreateTeamForm.  Would it be just null?  or not have a return statement at all?

Comment: If you don't have any data to pass to the template you can just return an empty array. If you return a string it will interpret that as pre-rendered HTML. I'm not sure what returning null would do.

Comment: I tried implementing your solution and it does not fully work.  When I submit the form and my doEditTeam function is called, the getCurrentTeam function returns null every time and as such the team never actually gets updated.  I tried adding some logs and found out that $this->getRequest()->param('ID') returns null every time.  Oddly enough, the page will load form at start and load in the values from the database, but it fails to update due to reason above.

Comment: So I did not change anything but it started working, the hidden ID started picking up the value and passing it in via the form.  What I don't understand is, how do I prevent users from changing that number and updating another team.

Comment: You just have to add logic to prevent a user from editing a team they don't have access to. You can do this either in the save method on the controller or throw an exception in onBeforeWrite on the team model.

Comment: I will be doing that by checking if they are the team  captain, what I'm trying to understand is if I am a team captain of Team 1 2 and 3.  And I go to team 3 and click Edit.  I can go to hidden form, change it to 1 and it will update all the information from team 3 to team 1.  This can be an issue if lets say I have unique team names, he can bypass now and have 2 teams with same name.  I can't think of all other scenarios that can happen here, but I would like to figure out a way to prevent that person from tempering with hidden field or somehow to validate that hidden field.

Comment: Sure, you have two easy options, each with their risks. First would be to use the session to store the ID instead of a hidden field. The alternative would be to include a second field with a hash of known data including the ID you're expecting him to be editing and check that the hash validates on save.

Comment: I was thinking of adding 2 hidden fields to the form and 1 additional field to the Team object.  The additional field would be a random passphrase.  Then I would pass in a time stamp and a hashed version of the time phrase with the time stamp as 2 additional fields.  Then hash it again against the record being updated.  The hashed phrase from the hidden field and the one I calculate again should come out identical, thus if they are not, something in the sequence has changed.  What do you think of this approach?  Do foresee any big risks to this approach?  I can even make all this as sessions.